# What does `data` argument in Statevector mean for `data` greater than size 2?

Tags: qiskit

Please refer to the topic on function Statevector:
https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.html#statevector

> instantiate a quantum circuit of one qubit: `QuantumCircuit(1)`
> instantiate the form of the state vector for this one qubit: `Statevector([sqrt(0.3), sqrt(0.7)])`

which says that this one qubit is described by a state vector of the form $|\psi\rangle = \sqrt(0.3)|0\rangle + \sqrt(0.7)|1\rangle$

Following the spirit of the documentation, the below must say
$|\psi\rangle = \sqrt(0.2)|0\rangle + \sqrt(0.2)|1\rangle + \sqrt(0.6)|2\rangle$

> `Statevector([sqrt(0.2), sqrt(0.2), sqrt(0.6)])`?

The code below evaluates programmatically but I am unsure it is sane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qiskit's `Statevector` is designed to represent the state of quantum systems of any dimension, not two-dimensional systems (i.e., qubits) only.

For example, the below code snippet creates a `Statevector` instance which represents a system composed of two subsystems, the first subsystem is two-dimensional and the second is three-dimensional:

```
psi = Statevector([1 / sqrt(6), 1 / sqrt(6), 1 / sqrt(6), 1 / sqrt(6), 1 / sqrt(6), 1 / sqrt(6)],
      dims=(2, 3))
```

On course when you initialize the `Statevector` using a `QuantumCircuit` the subsystems will be considered as two-dimensional.

Comment: It is still confusing to me. How does the Qiskit distinguish between the dimension of a subsystem? Is my guess correct that this is distinguish by the dimension argument seen in dims? First two element in the list L of a statevector is the first subsystem and the last 3 elements refers to the probability coefficient of the second subsystem?

Comment: Qiskit uses `dims` argument if exixts. Otherwise, it depends on the dimension of the `data` argument. If the dimension is a power of two ($d = 2^n$) the state will be initialized as an $n$-qubit state. If it is not a power of two the state will have a single $d$-dimensional subsystem.
In general, the subsystems could be entangled. So, we cannot say "this part of `data` is the state of the first subsystem, and that part is the state of the second subsystem". The whole array represents the state of the whole system.

Comment: This is such a odd way of defining an argument in the function...